# Update a row if a column shows out of date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code that worked for part but took ages to run (about 1700 rows). When I updated it to perform the whole function it now doesn't do anything- not sure where Ive gone wrong, and is there a version of code that would be quicker?
I'm still very new so do my code by searching what I want to do then bending it to suit.

I would like to check in column I for all dates that are less than the date in cell Z1. If any cells in the corresponding row say "Issued" I would like it to change to "Overdue".

```
Sub updateoverdue()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  Dim j As Long, i As Long, lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
  Dim sh_1, sh_3 As Worksheet

  Set sh_1 = Sheet6
  Set sh_3 = Sheet6

  lastRow1 = sh_1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

  For j = 2 To lastRow1
  Sheet6.Range("z1") = sh_1.Cells(j, 9).Value

  lastRow2 = sh_3.UsedRange.Rows.Count

  For i = 2 To lastRow2
      If sh_3.Cells(i, 9).Value < Sheet6.Range("z1") And sh_3.Cells(i, 10).Value = "Issued" Then
          sh_3.Cells(i, 10).Value = "Overdue"
      End If

      Next i

    Next j

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub
```

I got it working on just Column J but then it failed when I added in the Issued part. Plus I cant get it to change more than one column (J to W).

Comment: You should specify which sheet Z1 is on.

Comment: I've edited the code to specify the sheet (its all on one sheet). It didn't make any difference when I ran it.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code to see what's going on? Presumably the conditions are never satisfied. Check the size of your usedranges too.

Comment: You set both `sh_1` and `sh_3` to `Sheet6`.  Are those intended to be the same sheet?

Comment: I have, no errors come up, just nothing changes on the spreadsheet. The range used is aprox 1700 rows and 26 columns

Comment: Yes- I named them differently as they were for different stages and it was to stop me getting confused- error messages came up too when I tried to change it to just one

Comment: Alright, you are then also changing the date you're comparing against (Z1), to be what's already in column i.  This means that you'll never have a scenario where column i date is less than the Z1 date because they'll be the same.  I'm guessing you don't actually want the date in Z1 to change since that's the reference date?

Comment: If it works without the second condition, the problem must lie there so perhaps cells have trailing or leading spaces. Without seeing your data hard to diagnose really.

Comment: @tigeravatar - I think you may have hit on it.

Comment: Ah! OK that must be it. Ill swap it round and see. Thanks!

Comment: I have changed it to the following- I think ive removed bit where it was changing Z1 (probably left from the code id copied it off originally)

Comment: Ive changed it to this and it comes up with run time error 424

Comment: Sub updateoverdue()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Dim j As Long, lastRow1 As Long
    Dim sh_1 As Worksheet

    Set sh_1 = Sheet6

    lastRow1 = sh_1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For j = 2 To lastRow1

        If sh_3.Cells(i, 9).Value < Sheet6.Range("z1") And sh_3.Cells(i, 10).Value = "Issued" Then
            sh_3.Cells(i, 10).Value = "Overdue"
        End If

      Next j

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - as you can see it's unreadable.

Comment: Apologies I didn't know how to- still new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this and it worked fine:

```
Sub try()

Dim ws As Worksheet, lastrow As Long
Set ws = Sheet6
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To lastrow
    If ws.Cells(i, 9).Value < ws.Cells(1, 26).Value Then
        ws.Cells(i, 10).Value = "Overdue"
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, 9).Value > ws.Cells(1, 26).Value Then
        ws.Cells(i, 10).Value = "Issued"
    Else
        ws.Cells(i, 10).Value = "Due Today"
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Or you can just use an excel formula and drop it down the entire column:

```
=IF(I1<$Z$1, "Issued","Overdue")
```

Comment: Thank-you for this!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet6

    Dim TargetDate As Date
    TargetDate = ws.Range("Z1").Value2

    Dim DateList As Range
    Set DateList = ws.Range("I2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))
    If DateList.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No dates

    Dim DateCell As Range
    For Each DateCell In DateList.Cells
        If DateCell.Value2 > TargetDate And LCase(Trim(DateCell.Offset(, 1).Value)) = "issued" Then
            DateCell.Offset(, 1).Value = "Overdue"
        End If
    Next DateCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank-you Ill give it a go!